# how does compiler gets correct string without a receiver array from function?

Tags: c

**my program**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
char* mystrcat(char* , char* );\\ function declared as global
main()
{

    char dest[50]="hello";  \\destination string
    char src[50]="readers";  \\source string
    clrscr();
    mystrcat(dest,src);\\function calling but does not have receiving array 
    puts("after concatenation");                              \\ of strings
    puts(dest);\\shows "helloreaders"<-- how?
    getch();
    return 0;

}
char* mystrcat(char* des, char *sr)\\for concatenating two strings
{

    int i=0,j=0;
    while(des[i]!='\0')
    { i++;}
    while(sr[j]!='\0')  
    {
        des[i]=sr[j];
        i++;j++;

    }
    des[i]='\0';
    puts(sr);\\"readers"
    puts(des);\\"helloreaders"
    return sr;\\returning source string

}
```

**output:**

```
  readers
  helloreaders
```

after concatenating:

```
  helloreaders
```

I am returning only source string from `mystrcat()`. But how compiler knows the modified destination string? Since I declare the function globally the compiler knows the modified string?

Comment: Does it compile? The correct delimiter for line comments is `//`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not because of `return sr`, rather it is because `char* mystrcat(char* des, char *sr)` modified its argument ( `des` ).  Even if you change the return value to just an int, the result will be same. The reason is when you pass a `char[]` variable to a function, you just pass a pointer, anything you did inside the function to the variable will be reflected to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

When you called function

```
mystrcat(dest,src);\\function calling but does not have receiving array
```

you passed as arguments two arrays that are implicitly converted to pointers to first elements of each array.

So inside the function you deal with addresses of the memory extents occupied by the arrays. And you write in the memory occupied by the destination array elements of the source array

```
while(sr[j]!='\0')  
{
 des[i]=sr[j];
 i++;j++;
 }
 des[i]='\0';
```

because `des` and `sr` hold addresses of first elements of the arrays.

So the memory occupied by array `dest` was overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving mystrcat() a *pointer* to dest and when it writes through that pointer, it changes dest directly. It doesn't matter what the function returns. des[] in mystrcat() is not a *copy* of dest[] in the main program, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

because parameters you pass to the function are points,arrays they point to are changed, but these points are not changed